# C++ byte-patching for game

Tags: c++, file, byte, exe, patch

How would I make a system so I could take an old .exe, take a new updated one, and generate a patch file or something like that, that patches the different bytes between the old and new file? I don't even know where to start.

Comment: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/185/how-do-i-add-functionality-to-an-existing-binary-executable

Comment: Is this for an update system? Then don’t bother. Even at times of small bandwidth binary patches were rarely worth doing. It’s easier (and entirely feasible, size wise) to replace whole files.

Comment: This has been solved generically (i.e. for any kind of file) - see e.g. http://xdelta.org/ No need to roll your own version.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph nobody wants to download a 200+ mb file daily... and I don't want to UPLOAD a 200+ mb file daily...

Comment: @Omega No binary is 200 MB. It will usually be a few kilobytes.

Comment: I don't want to distribute art separately. It's all packed into an exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you would need to know the format of the executable or exe.

Secondly, you would need to know where in the executable to apply the patch.

Also, what kind of patch, is it data or executable?

Are you developing the patch or applying the patch?
There exist many different patching utilities.  Perhaps you could use one of those?

Here are the steps for a simple patch:

1. Make a backup copy of the original.
2. Open original as binary, write-able.
3. Seek to the offset needing to be patched.
4. Overwrite existing code with new data.
5. Save file.

A more complex patch may involve:
Inserting a function call in the code.
  Need to calculate the relative address of the new function in order to generate the call instruction.
Appending the function code to the end of the executable (may need to change the executable format).

We would need more information in order to help you more.